# Similar error and R2 on Multiple Linear Regression and Random Forest, but very different predictions for new values?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, random-forest, scikit-learn, model-evaluation

I'm trying to compare a **Multiple Linear Regression** model against a **Random Forest Regression** model using sklearn. I have 4 features and one continuous variable to predict.

I am training on 70% of the data and testing on the remaining 30%, the original dataset size is ~10000 samples.

I have set a random state for splitting the data and also tuned the parameters for RF using cross validation and grid search `(n_estimators=1675, min_samples_split=10, min_samples_leaf=1, max_features="sqrt", max_depth=40, bootstrap=True)`. The results are very similar with as little as 30 trees.

The metrics I get for **Multiple Linear Regression** (test data):

> R2: 0.4556
>   MAE: 0.0193
>   RMSE: 0.0246

The metrics I get for **Random Forest Regression** (test data):

> R2: 0.5111
>   MAE: 0.0183
>   RMSE: 0.0233

But when I use the same set of new values to generate a new prediction (out of sample) I get very different values (the range should be approximately 0-1):

> MLR: 0.3894
>   RF: 0.1442

Furthermore I looked at the QQ-plot for the residuals and it seems to be fairly straight for Multiple Linear Regression, while it seems to curve in opposite directions at each end for Random Forest.

I'm new to RF but this seems very odd to me, is there any possible explanation? Is it plausible the error be so similar yet the prediction be so different? In which case, what model should be trusted more?

Comment: Have you come across the word “overfitting” yet?

Comment: Have you come across the word “overfitting” yet? And what metric are you calculating out of sample, $R^2?$

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your comment. I have come across overfitting, however I believe Random Forest is already unlikely to overfit, especially after tuning the parameters. Moreover, when checking the out of bag R2 score the value is very similar to the test R2. Do you believe the issue might be overfitting? In regards to the metrics out of sample, they are not metrics, they are predictions of the target variable y given a set of new inputs x.

Comment: So both methods give plausible results that happen to be different?

Comment: Correct, the models metrics seem to be reasonable and similar but the results are very different, even though plausible.

Comment: I am not sure what problem you see. The models use fairly different methods of making their predictions, so of course they will disagree about their predictions. What's the true value for the predictors you used?

Comment: Unfortunately for this dataset I don't have the true value, which makes it difficult to evaluate the predictions. In this case, if both models are correct, how can I pick one over the other? Is it even possible to find out which is closer to a true value?

Comment: Could it be that Random Forest struggles to extrapolate and predict a value outside the range that it was trained on? The input values that I am using are not present in the training data.